# Create local setting in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have two pages , my label in page one, and page 2 is my setting page,
I want change size of my label with my setting page . how should I do this?

Comment: Do you want this change to persist or not? If you do, then have some sort of database (sqllite, realm) in your app that keeps track of label size and then in the viewmodel or code behind (so xaml.cs) of your page one you can read from the DB and assign it that value. If you don't need any persistence, just have it so that when you navigate away from page 2 to page 1 you pass it the new size

Comment: Use messagingcenter to achieve it

Comment: [Dynamic Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/dynamic) is the way to go. If you want persistence, take a look at Xamarin Essentials [Preferences API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android). No need to build out a db.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using xaml

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/dynamic

Maybe something like this

```
<x:Double x:Key="SmallCaption">12</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="BigCaption">14</x:Double>

<Style x:Key="CaptionLabel" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource Caption}" />
</Style>
```

```
public partial class DynamicStylesPage : ContentPage
{
    bool isBigFontSize = true;

    public DynamicStylesPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        Resources ["Caption"] = Resources ["SmallCaption"];
    }

    void OnButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isBigFontSize) {
            Resources ["Caption"] = Resources ["BigCaption"];
            isBigFontSize = false;
        } else {
            Resources ["Caption"] = Resources ["SmallCaption"];
            isBigFontSize = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Haven't tested... but I think it should be more or less that way...